# How do i get the url that kendo builds on the client

Tags: javascript, filter, kendo-ui, odata, kendo-datasource

For instance, kendo generates the following url for odata

http://gmovpwbwebdev01:8001/odata/PSellerPartnerMPNLocation?%24format=json&%24expand=PSeller%2C+Geography&%24top=20&%24orderby=PSEllerName&%24filter=((Geography%2FSubsidiaryDistrictId+eq+11182+or+Geography%2FSubsidiaryDistrictId+eq+11179)+and+(Geography%2FSubsidiaryId+eq+161+or+Geography%2FSubsidiaryId+eq+49)+and+Geography%2FAreaId+eq+5)&%24count=true

How do I retrieve the url that is build on the client.  I need to send the odata filter to the server for different processing and I don't want to build the string myself if kendo is already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo does indeed generate the url according to endpoint, filters, sort etc applied to the widget.

Edit: below is how to access the request url.

```
dataSource: {
  transport: {
      read: {
         url: url,
         dataType: type, // "json"
         beforeSend: function (e, request) {
            var requestUrl = request.url
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, this appears to give me the options configured when setting up the datasource but not provide the filter that was built (i.e. ?%24format=json&%24expand=PSeller%2C+Geography&%24top=20&%24orderby=PSEllerName&%24filter=((Geography%2FSubsidiaryDistrictId+eq+11182+or+Geography%2FSubsidiaryDistrictId+eq+11179)+and+(Geography%2FSubsidiaryId+eq+161+or+Geography%2FSubsidiaryId+eq+49)+and+Geography%2FAreaId+eq+5)&%24count=true)

Comment: Thanks for the help!